# Transition from parliamentary to presidential Republic?

Tags: parliament, political-system, president, republic, political-transitions

Did any country in recent century successfully transitioned from parliamentary to presidential Republic (both of them reasonably unambiguously democratic - I'm pretty open as far as inclusiveness)?

Comment: France did, I think, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: @Sklivvz - De Gaulle invitation? Make that an answer :)

Comment: If you want to investigate further on this topic, Turkey is planning to make this transition, but the main reason is to increase authority of the current prime minister in future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, France did in 1958.

The current French fifth Republic is a semi-presidential system which replaced the previous parliamentary system in 1958.

> The Fifth Republic is the fifth and current republican constitution of France, introduced on 4 October 1958. The Fifth Republic emerged from the collapse of the French Fourth Republic, replacing the prior parliamentary government with a semi-presidential system.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Fifth_Republic

Answer (score 0):

Yes Nigeria did. The fourth republic is the current republican constitution of Nigeria. The fourth republic of Nigeria emerged due to the collapse of the third republic. In-fact, Nigeria has undergone through various changes of political systems ranging from the Monarchical system - The Modified Monarchy-Parliamentary System-Military System- and finally, the presidential system in which it currently operates.

Answer (score 0):

In a short period between gaining independence and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_Russian_constitutional_crisis Russian Federation was more of a parliamentary republic, at least on paper. The president wasn't happy about it and used some tanks to literally destroy the parliament and turn Russia into a presidential republic.